# See functions, classes, or methods in Emacs console mode

Tags: emacs

I use emacs in the console mode. Is there a mode that is like speedbar for browsing functions, classes, or methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [SrSpeedbar](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SrSpeedbar), which is a

> mode [to] make [SpeedBar](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpeedBar) show in [the] **Current Frame**

[image]
<sub>(source: [emacswiki.org](http://www.emacswiki.org/pics/static/SrSpeedbarInXterm.png))</sub>

SrSpeedbar can be installed via [MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/), or manually using the [elisp on EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/sr-speedbar.el).

Comment: Super! I'm using python, but the speedbar won't show my classes or methods. I'd tried using speedbar-add-supported-extension ".py" but that did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ToddMatsumoto, perhaps SrSpeedbar isn't fully compatible with the newest version of Speedbar? I get Python class and method navigation out of the box with regular Speedbar, but none listed using SrSpeedbar...

Comment: Thanks Chris, I went and tried normal speedbar and have the same issue. Which version of emacs/speedbar do you have?

Comment: @ToddMatsumoto, Emacs 24.3.50.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. `speedbar-version` 1.0. I don't see classes and methods immediately when launching speedbar; I have to expand the file node by clicking on the "file plus" icon.

Comment: @ToddMatsumoto, if you are only looking for Python support there is another option, but it depends on [`emacs-jedi`](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi): [`emacs-jedi-direx`](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi-direx).